# Jquery fade effect

Tags: jquery, fade, effect

I need some jquery help. I have a simple image gallery and I'd like to add some jquery effect (particulary fading in/out of the images in #actimg). Keep in mind, Im not very familiar with jquery.

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPic (whichpic) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
  document.getElementById('actimg').src = whichpic.href; 
  return false; 
 } else {
  return true;
 } 
}
</script>
```

and body

```
<ul>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="images/girl_01.jpg"><img height="50px" width="50px" src="images/girl_01.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="images/girl_02.jpg"><img height="50px" width="50px" src="images/girl_02.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="images/girl_03.jpg"><img height="50px" width="50px" src="images/girl_03.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>

<img id="actimg" src="images/girl_04.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: no naked girls there :) ... just image gallery with fashion and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function showPic (whichpic) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
  $('#actimg').fadeOut('slow');
  document.getElementById('actimg').src = whichpic.href; 
  $('#actimg').fadeIn('slow');
  return false; 
 } else {
  return true;
 } 
}
```

I have added two lines around the line where you change the source of the #actimg img tag. The one just before fades the #actimg out and the one just after fades it back in.

---- EDIT ----

change:

```
  $('#actimg').fadeOut('slow');
  document.getElementById('actimg').src = whichpic.href; 
  $('#actimg').fadeIn('slow');
```

to:

```
  $('#actimg').fadeOut(250);
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('actimg').src = whichpic.href; 
      $('#actimg').fadeIn(250);
  }, 250);
```

This will fadeOut the #actimg element, then it will change the source of that element and fadeIn the element. Note that the fadeOut duration should be the same or less than the duration of the timeout so that the fade can complete before the source of the image is changed.

Comment: this seems like the effect Id like to achieve, but now when I click on some image I can see this image before it flashes/fades. 
ps. (I am using latest jquery 1.6.2)

Comment: ah yeah I've had that problem before as well, the way I got around it was to add a timeout to changing the source of the image, see my edit above

Comment: Using setTimeout to get around that is quite hackish... why don't you take a look at other less complicated answers with better results.

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery already, using "document.getElementById" is a little silly.

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
$("li a").click(function(){
       $("#actimg").fadeOut();
        var imghref = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#actimg").attr("src",imghref);
        $("#actimg").fadeIn();
```

}
and get rid of your showpic function...

Answer (score 0):

In jquery to select an element by id you use "#"+id selector.

```
function showPic (whichpic) {
  $('#actimg').attr("src", whichpic.href).hide().fadeIn(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ShankarSangoli's answer looks great. However, if you want the displayed image to fade away before the new one fades in, which is an awesome effect, do this:

```
function showPic(whichPic) {
  $('#actimg').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('#actimg').attr('src', $(whichPic).attr('href'));
    $('#actimg').fadeIn('fast');
  });
}
```

This takes advantage of the callback on fadeOut. The callback is called once the animation is finished.